# Save model without fitted values in R

Tags: r, model, prediction

Let's say I have a linear regression model like this

```
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
fit <- lm(a ~ b)
```

The fit object is a list that contains the coefficients and the data and the fitted values and so on and so forth. However, if I want to predict on unseen data I only need the model itself, so basically the coefficients. In the example that really doesn't matter, but I actually have models that are (unnecessarily) hundreds of MB big.

How can only keep the stuff that is really needed to predict on unseen data?

...and still be able to use `predict()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right some elements of this list can be replaced by NULL. This should not impact predict and therefore could be used correctly. You just have to make sure that those elements are not needed in the predict.

You could for instance do this :

```
fit$data <- NULL
fit$y <- NULL
fit$linear.predictors <- NULL
fit$weights <- NULL
fit$fitted.values <- NULL
fit$model <- NULL
fit$prior.weights <- NULL
fit$residuals <- NULL
fit$effects <- NULL
```

More details are provided in this link. 
http://blog.yhat.com/posts/reducing-your-r-memory-footprint-by-7000x.html

Comment: Didn't try it, yet, but it seems reasonable. It's just a clunky, though. I really thought there would be some built-in function to do this for all possible models.